# Shut Indexes off vs removing/replacing in MySql?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I was told that inserting into a table with Indexes is slow. Is there way to get around removing indexes or creating/inserting to tabel w/o indexes and then recreating indexes afterward to simply tell mysql to ignore the indexes on the insert and to reindex afterwards?

Comment: Inserting into a table with indexes is *potentially slowER*. A lot depends on how many indexes you have, their type, your I/O and CPU performance, and how much data you have. Benchmark it first to see if it matters in your case.

Comment: Do you understand *why* inserting into a heavily-indexed table is slow?  What makes you think that this idea is going to be faster?  More importantly, have you *measured* the performance of your queries and determined *specifically* what makes them slow?  Instead of re-engineering your entire database because someone once told you that some vague concept might be slower than some other vague concept, *measure* your performance and *identify* the problems to be solved.

Comment: @David I did in fact test inserting into a non-indexed vs indexed version of the table and the non-indexed version was quite a bit faster. So moving fwd as I need to re-run this process frequently, I am trying to figure out exactly what I posted; will I be better of removing indexes, inserting, recreating indexes or is there a way to simply tell MySql 'ignore the indexes on insert'

Comment: @user3649739: Generally it's "slower" because the table needs to re-calculate the index after the insert.  What you're suggesting is that, instead, you'd just manually tell the table to re-calculate the index after the insert.  I doubt that would save much performance.  And it's really not clear what "ignoring the indexes" would accomplish.  If the index isn't updated, what use is it?

Comment: @David It simply seemed like it might be an option to another solution I read about which is to do a Create Table(Insert From) on a new unindexeds table and add the indexes back,

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Indexes are usually worth a *lot* for `SELECTs`, while costing only a *little* during `INSERTs`.  Don't turn them off.

**Long answer:**

- The advice you were given applies only in some obscure case.
- When initially loading a very large table, it is *sometimes* better to have no indexes (except `PRIMARY KEY`, in the case of InnoDB) while loading, then add all the indexes at once.
- Once the table is populated, turning of the indexes (for adding more rows) is almost *never* practical.
- An index on a "flag" (true/false, M/F, yes/no/maybe) column is almost never used.  `DROP` it.
- If you have "indexed every column", then I have choice 4-letter words for you.  Most of your indexes will never be used.
- If you have never built a "composite" index -- that is an index with more than one column in it -- then your indexes may not be as good as needed.
- That is, having a "few" indexes is good.